# iOS Autolayout constrain issue | App crashing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to add constrains to subviews of screen at runtime. This is causing crash. Below is my code:

```
for var i in 0 ..< 5{
        let aController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "design")
        let itemView = aController.view
        //itemView!.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(i) * itemView!.frame.width
        itemView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        itemView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemView!, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        itemView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemView!, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        itemView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemView!, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        itemView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemView!, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))

        scrollView.addSubview(itemView!)
    }
```

And the error I am getting is as under:

> 2017-10-23 10:39:37.087674+0530 RollerCoasterPotential[998:22689]
>   [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the
>   constraint:
>
> When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of
>   that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint
>   needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on
>   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
>
> 2017-10-23 10:39:37.087924+0530 RollerCoasterPotential[998:22689] ***
>   Assertion failure in -[UIView
>   _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3688.4/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:734
>   2017-10-23 10:39:37.177966+0530 RollerCoasterPotential[998:22689] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up
>   layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'

Comment: How is scrollView defined and added in the ViewController?

Comment: ScrollView is added via Interface Builder (Not added dynamically).

Comment: First, I don't think you need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false for scrollview. You should set it false for each itemView. Second, if you are using Autolayout, you dont need to set itemview's frame's origin. Third, you should create autolayout constraints(to satisfy position and size and not just trailing constraint) for itemview and add it to scrollview. Don't do the other way.

Comment: Please see the updated code @PuneetSharma. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: included an aswer

Comment: Add  scrollView.addSubview(itemView!) line before setting constraints and remove this line from end.

Comment: You need to increment the top constraint dynamically. eg : i*some value+constant

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func addConstraints() {
    var itemViews:[UIView] = []
    for i in 0 ..< 5 {
        let aController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "design")
        let itemView = aController.view
        itemView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(itemView!)
        itemViews.append(itemView!)
        scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: itemView!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: itemView!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        if(i == 0) {
            scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: itemView!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        } else {
            let previousView = itemViews[i-1]
            itemView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: previousView!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:itemView!, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        }

        if i == 4 {
            scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: itemView!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: All views are coming together. Overlapping with each other.

Comment: Nope. It's crashing the app. First element should have fixed top,bottom,leading and trailing space but subsequent itemView should have only horizontal space. Top and Bottom should be fixed. Isn't it?

Comment: @TechBee: First item should have top, leading, trailing constraints to superview. 2nd, 3rd, 4th items should have leading, trailing to superview and top to previous view. last item(5th item), should have leading, trailing to superview, top to previous view and bottom to superview.

Comment: This is a classic problem. Have you faced this kind of problem @Puneet ?

Comment: @TechBee:I dont know why all your views were coming together. They shouldn't. At runtime, you may be getting constraint specific error on console, which may help to debug further.

Comment: Actually when you enable paging than it's become difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding constraints before adding item in scrollview. Resulting in below error,

**'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'**

Instead, add item in scrollview and then apply constraints. Probably something like this. (Assuming your rest of the constraints are good.)

```
for var i in 0 ..< 5{
    let aController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "design")
    let itemView = aController.view

    //itemView!.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(i) * itemView!.frame.width
    itemView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Below add your view

    scrollView.addSubview(itemView!)

    itemView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemView!, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
    itemView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemView!, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    itemView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemView!, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
    itemView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemView!, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))

}
```